# vimscript: how does `confirm` behave when vim is compiled without dialog support?

Tags: vim

According to the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#confirm()), `confirm()` only works when vim is compiled with the `dialog` option enabled.  However, I have put it in a function and just discovered that `dialog` is not enabled for my vim build, but `confirm()` is still working fine.

How does `confirm` behave when `dialog` support is not enabled, and is it safe to include it in my function without dialog support?